shiro uses a custom filter to report an error "No SecurityManager accessible to the calling code"
Originally, my filterChainDefinitionMap was filterChainDefinitionMap.put("/login/**","anon"); it responded normally when calling the interface, but now I have a need. All "/login/**" need to be recorded after successful login. Some information, so I customized a CustomLoginFilter and inherited it from BasicHttpAuthenticationFilter, overriding the onLoginSuccess method. Then change filterChainDefinitionMap to filterChainDefinitionMap.put("/login/**", "customLoginFilter"); At this time, it is found that the return value of the interface call is {"timestamp":1713163170942,"status":500,"error":"Internal Server Error","path":"/login/local"}.After checking the console, I found that the error message was org.apache.shiro.UnavailableSecurityManagerException: No SecurityManager accessible to the calling code, either bound to the org.apache.shiro.util.ThreadContext or as a vm static singleton.  This is an invalid application configuration.
I don't know if my shiro configuration is incorrect. I checked the information on the Internet, and one of the methods is to manually bind securityManage to the current thread, namely ThreadContext.bind(securityManager);At this time, I found that the HTTP status code of the interface call response changed to 401 and no logs were generated on the console.
The following is my shiro configuration class.
@Slf4j
@Configuration
public class ShiroConfig {

    @Value("${spring.data.redis.host}")
    private String host;

    @Value("${spring.data.redis.port}")
    private int port;

    @Value("${redis.biz_cache_time.session}")
    private Long sessionExpireTime;

    @Autowired
    private RedisTemplate<Serializable, Session> redisShiroTemplate;


    @Bean
    public ShiroFilterFactoryBean getShiroFilterBean(DefaultWebSecurityManager defaultWebSecurityManager){
        ShiroFilterFactoryBean bean = new ShiroFilterFactoryBean();

        bean.setSecurityManager(defaultWebSecurityManager);


        LinkedHashMap<String, Filter> filterMap = new LinkedHashMap<>();
        filterMap.put("customLoginFilter",new CustomLoginFilter());
        bean.setFilters(filterMap);


        Map<String,String> filterChainDefinitionMap = new LinkedHashMap<>();
        filterChainDefinitionMap.put("/login/**", "customLoginFilter");
        bean.setFilterChainDefinitionMap(filterChainDefinitionMap);

        bean.setLoginUrl("/login/to-login");

        return bean;
    }


    @Bean(name="securityManager")
    public DefaultWebSecurityManager getDefaultWebSecurityManager(AbstractAuthenticator abstractAuthenticator){
        DefaultWebSecurityManager securityManager = new DefaultWebSecurityManager();
        securityManager.setSessionManager(sessionManager());
        securityManager.setAuthenticator(abstractAuthenticator);
        return securityManager;
    }


    @Bean("lifecycleBeanPostProcessor")
    public static LifecycleBeanPostProcessor lifecycleBeanPostProcessor() {
        return new LifecycleBeanPostProcessor();
    }



    @Bean
    public AbstractAuthenticator abstractAuthenticator() {
        ModularRealmAuthenticator authenticator = new MyCustomModularRealmAuthenticator();
        authenticator.setAuthenticationStrategy(new AtLeastOneSuccessfulStrategy());
        List<Realm> realms = new ArrayList<>();
        realms.add(customRealm());
        authenticator.setRealms(realms);
        return authenticator;
    }


    @Bean
    public DefaultWebSessionManager sessionManager() {
        StatelessSessionManager sessionManager = new StatelessSessionManager();
        sessionManager.setSessionIdCookie(cookie());
        sessionManager.setGlobalSessionTimeout(sessionExpireTime);
        sessionManager.setSessionDAO(redisSessionDAO());
        sessionManager.setDeleteInvalidSessions(true);
        return sessionManager;
    }

    @Bean
    public CustomRealm customRealm() {
        return new CustomRealm();
    }

    @Bean
    public SimpleCookie cookie() {
        SimpleCookie cookie = new SimpleCookie("Authorization");
        cookie.setPath("/");
        return cookie;
    }


    @Bean
    SessionDAO redisSessionDAO() {
        return new RedisSessionDAO(MagicValueConst.SHIRO_REDIS_PREFIX, sessionExpireTime, redisShiroTemplate);
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthorizationAttributeSourceAdvisor authorizationAttributeSourceAdvisor(DefaultWebSecurityManager securityManager){
        AuthorizationAttributeSourceAdvisor authorizationAttributeSourceAdvisor = new AuthorizationAttributeSourceAdvisor();
        authorizationAttributeSourceAdvisor.setSecurityManager(securityManager);
        return authorizationAttributeSourceAdvisor;
    }

    @Bean
    public static DefaultAdvisorAutoProxyCreator getDefaultAdvisorAutoProxyCreator(){
        DefaultAdvisorAutoProxyCreator defaultAdvisorAutoProxyCreator = new DefaultAdvisorAutoProxyCreator();
        defaultAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.setProxyTargetClass(true);
        return defaultAdvisorAutoProxyCreator;
    }
}

My maven configuration is as follows：
    ...
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.5</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    ...
       <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
       </properties>
    ...
            <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.shiro</groupId>
            <artifactId>shiro-spring-boot-web-starter</artifactId>
            <version>1.13.0</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.apache.shiro</groupId>
                    <artifactId>shiro-spring</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.shiro</groupId>
            <artifactId>shiro-spring</artifactId>
            <classifier>jakarta</classifier>
            <version>1.13.0</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.apache.shiro</groupId>
                    <artifactId>shiro-core</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.apache.shiro</groupId>
                    <artifactId>shiro-web</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.shiro</groupId>
            <artifactId>shiro-core</artifactId>
            <classifier>jakarta</classifier>
            <version>1.13.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.shiro</groupId>
            <artifactId>shiro-web</artifactId>
            <classifier>jakarta</classifier>
            <version>1.13.0</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.apache.shiro</groupId>
                    <artifactId>shiro-core</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>



It look like there is a lot of extra configuration here. My suggestion would be to reduce the complexity until you get everything working. Take a look at the example in the Shiro tree:
https://github.com/apache/shiro/blob/f15073b8f7b6bc38af0575f6442885c945b319ab/samples/spring-boot-3-web/src/main/java/org/apache/shiro/samples/WebApp.java#L86-L92
I'm also a little unsure of the question. It seems you are extending BasicHttpAuthenticationFilter and setting up a stateless session manager, that uses cookies?
A flow that is similar to Basic Auth, wouldn't start with a request to a specific login URL (and wouldn't need cookies).
In general be cautious of overriding the default configuration as you may bypass some of the default security settings that you get out of the box.
Can you create a simplistic example on GitHub (or somewhere similar) and define the steps to reproduce this problem?
